# Como alterar a cor da StatusBar

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou tentando alterar as cores da minha StatusBar, porém ao tentar alterar a colorPrimaryDark (primeira barra, onde fica bateria, horário, etc...) a cor não é alterada.

Criei um xml com os valores das cores utilizadas

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<color name = "primary">#162d50</color>
<color name = "primary_dark">#010101</color>
<color name = "textprimary">#FFFFFF</color>


</resources>
```

E minha styles.xml está assim

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">

        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textprimary</item>


</style>

</resources>
```

Estou conseguindo alterar todas as cores, background, cor da barra de título, cor do texto, porém a colorPrimaryDark, independente do valor inserido não altera a cor, permanece sempre preto, alguem poderia me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 2):

Para alterar a cor da StatusBar deve utilizar o atributo `android:statusBarColor`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textprimary</item>

    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/cor_da_statusbar</item>
</style>
```

Referências:

- [Personalizar a barra de status](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar).